# Wordpress displays page instead of 404 error without https prefix

Tags: wordpress, iis, http-status-code-404

My Wordpress install on iis displays a specific page instead of 404 for a missing page when using www. without https:// ie:

https://www.mydomain.co.uk/cabbage goes to 404 error page

www.mydomain.co.uk/cabbage goes to a page on my site, if I disable this page it just goes to another rather than the 404 page.

Have tried re-saving permalinks and disabling redirect plug-in.

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS are controlled by different site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background So if you missed a proper one for HTTPS, 404 is not a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WordPress documentation, if you are running IIS 7+, you will need to also have the URL Rewrite 1.1+ module installed as well. This is a pretty standard module and is often already installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
     <match url="*"/>
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> If you already had a web.config file, just add the tags that are missing, without deleting any of the existing settings.

Comment: I've checked the web.config file and it contains the lines you provided, no mention of www though.